# Live bytes growing with ARC over 200 MB on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

When I run my iPhone app with instruments, it shows the live bytes growing when I go back and forth from displaying a modal view controller, but the app doesn't get killed even after using over 200 MB.

What exactly is happening here? I'm I consuming a lot of memory?
Btw, I am using iOS 7 with ARC.

The image below shows the live bytes.
[image: Instruments]

Thank you.

UPDATE:
Code in my modal view controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActionCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Action *action = self.actions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = action.title;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = self.sectionColors[indexPath.section];

    CustomCellBackgroundView *customCellBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackgroundView alloc] init];
    customCellBackgroundView.borderColor = self.sectionColors[indexPath.section];
    customCellBackgroundView.fillColor = [self.sectionColors[indexPath.section] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];

    if ([self.actions[indexPath.section] count] == 1) {
        customCellBackgroundView.position = CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        customCellBackgroundView.position = CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop;
    } else if (indexPath.row == [self.actions[indexPath.section] count] - 1) {
        customCellBackgroundView.position = CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom;
    } else {
        customCellBackgroundView.position = CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle;
    }

    cell.backgroundView = customCellBackgroundView;

    return cell;
}
```

The modal view controller keeps a weak delegate to the main view controller that calls the modal.
And doesn't [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; releases the modal view controller for good (and all its subviews and variables)?

Btw, the CustomCellBackgroundView is probably not the problem, because I have another modal view controller that uses it in the same way, but does not increase memory usage.

The weird thing is that even after using 200 MB, the app is not killed, why is that (not running on simulator, running on the actual iPhone)?

Comment: Without seeing the involved code this is impossible to debug. Normally when I have leaks with ARC it's because I use a core foundation object and forget that ARC doesn't handle those.

Comment: Perhaps you have a reference cycle. Most likely you modal view controller is never being released.

Comment: ARC doesn't mean that you have clean memory! As long as you have strong variables or hold references to objects they stay alive.

Comment: Most of the memory is being used by cell backgrounds it looks like... Are you properly using dequeue to set up your cells?

Comment: ArtOfWarfare, I just updated the question with some code to show you how I'm dequeueing the cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter that took me some time to understand, but even though ark is amazing, and helps allot! You cannot code a complex app, and throw all data management to be handled by ARK with out your help.

Every viewController, you must have a "ViewWillDissapear" method, and there, you need to turn nil every object that you used, so ARK knows that its all right to get rid of it.

//Important 
If you use images in your app, its very important that you release them after, by turning them to nil.
if you use any context, you must release by hand!
make shore you are not keeping to manny views on top of each ether!
If you use audio file, you must release it after!

last note, make sure u are not holding "strong" references to objects that there is no need to hold strong reference to. because they will never be released.

Hope this helps, 
happy programming.

Comment: If I have a view controller with a property like @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array; do I have to do self.array = nil? Doesn't this array gets deallocated when the view controller goes away (no more references to it)?

Comment: First of all, view controller, goes away depending on the situation. lets say, you use a navigation controller method "PushViewController", the view is still in the stack of views. second, a Strong reference is both ways. that is the difference from "Weak" reference, as long as one of the two objects is alive, he is still holds a strong reference to the ether.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the stupid question, it was a rookie mistake, the problem was that I was creating a retain cycle by calling a method on self inside a block that was stored in my view controller.